# Replacing substrings of nested arrays with a value from another array

Tags: php

The loop below outputs from the $defaultValues ​​values, there are 2 nested arrays in this array which are "colors" and "lessons".

This loop also takes the substring values ​​from the $search array and replaces them with the values ​​from the $replace.

**Question:** How to replace nested array clause value "colors" and "lessons" from $defaultValues ​​

values: "colors"=>["4", "5", "6"] and "lessons" =>["7 " , " 8", "9"] from $replace"

I can't figure out how to do this, my current code outputs this:

```
Name: 1
Age: 2
Whe are u from: 3
Your favorite color: 4
Choose courses: 7
Your comment: 10
```

I would like the code to output this:

```
Name: 1
Age: 2
Whe are u from: 3
Your favorite color: 4,5,6
Choose courses: 7,8,9
Your comment: 10
```

```js
$defaultValues = [
  "name"     =>  "Name:                   <div class='user'>     write your name                     </div>", 
  "age"      =>  "Age:                    <div class='age'>      enter your age                      </div>",
  "from"     =>  "Whe are u from:         <div class='from'>     write where are you from            </div>", 
  "colors"   =>  ["Your favorite color:   <div class='colors'>   you didn't say your favorite color  </div>"],        
  "lessons"  =>  ["Choose courses:        <div class='lessons'>  you have not chosen any course      </div>"],
  "comment"  =>  "Your comment:           <div class='comment'>  no comments                         </div>",     
];
 
$search = [
  "name"     =>  "write your name", 
  "age"      =>  "enter your age", 
  "from"     =>  "write where are you from", 
  "colors"   =>  ["you didn't say your favorite color"],        
  "lessons"  =>  ["you have not chosen any course"],
  "comment"  =>  "no comments",   
];
 
$replace = [
  "name"     =>  "1", 
  "age"      =>  "2",
  "from"     =>  "3",
  "colors"   =>  ["4", "5", "6"],        
  "lessons"  =>  ["7", "8", "9"],
  "comment"  =>  "10",       
];
 
 
foreach($defaultValues as $key => $items){
  echo "<div class='block'>";
 
  if(is_array($items)){
    foreach($items as $child){
        $items = str_replace($search[$key], $replace[$key], $child);
    }
  }
 
  echo $items = str_replace($search[$key], $replace[$key], $items);   
 
  echo "</div>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `implode` to parse the array into a comma-separated string for output!

```
<?php
// example code

$defaultValues = [
    "name"     =>  "Name:                   <div class='user'>     write your name                     </div>", 
    "age"      =>  "Age:                    <div class='age'>      enter your age                      </div>",
    "from"     =>  "Whe are u from:         <div class='from'>     write where are you from            </div>", 
    "colors"   =>  ["Your favorite color:   <div class='colors'>   you didn't say your favorite color  </div>"],        
    "lessons"  =>  ["Choose courses:        <div class='lessons'>  you have not chosen any course      </div>"],
    "comment"  =>  "Your comment:           <div class='comment'>  no comments                         </div>",     
];
 
$search = [
    "name"     =>  "write your name", 
    "age"      =>  "enter your age", 
    "from"     =>  "write where are you from", 
    "colors"   =>  ["you didn't say your favorite color"],        
    "lessons"  =>  ["you have not chosen any course"],
    "comment"  =>  "no comments",   
];
 
$replace = [
    "name"     =>  "1", 
    "age"      =>  "2",
    "from"     =>  "3",
    "colors"   =>  ["4", "5", "6"],        
    "lessons"  =>  ["7", "8", "9"],
    "comment"  =>  "10",       
];
 
 
foreach($defaultValues as $key => $items){
    echo "<div class='block'>";
    $replace_item = (is_array($replace[$key]) ? implode(",", $replace[$key]) : $replace[$key]);
    if(is_array($items)){
        foreach($items as $child){
            $items = str_replace($search[$key], $replace_item, $child);
        }
    }

    echo $items = str_replace($search[$key], $replace_item, $items);   
    echo "</div>";  
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know that the ternary operator could return something.

I thought the ternary operator is the same as if/else because if/else returns nothing.

Is a ternary operator a return function?

How to understand when a ternary operator returns something and when it doesn't?

Comment: @Homersx It isn't returning per se. It sets a variable based on a condition. The "long hand" for the above ternary operator is: `if (is_array($replace[$key])) then { $replace_item = implode(",", $replace[$key]); } else { $replace_item = $replace[$key]; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to join the array of colors and lessons to create the string to replace the corresponding placeholders you may use the function `implode`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Here's the code fragment:

```
if(is_array($items)){
  foreach($items as $child){
    $replaceListImploded = implode(",", $replace[$key]);
    $items = str_replace($search[$key], $replaceListImploded, $child);
  }
}
```

The corresponding output:

```
<div class='block'>
  Your favorite color:   <div class='colors'>   4,5,6  </div>
</div>
<div class='block'>
  Choose courses:        <div class='lessons'>  7,8,9      </div>
</div>
```

Here's the whole snippet: https://onlinephp.io/c/098a6

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $items = is_array($search[$key]) ? implode(',', $replace[$key]) : str_replace($search[$key], $replace[$key], $items);
```

will output you looking for

Comment: I didn't even know that the ternary operator could return something.

I thought the ternary operator is the same as if/else because if/else returns nothing.

Is a ternary operator a return function?

How to understand when a ternary operator returns something and when it doesn't?

Comment: @Homersx, ternary operator does not return anything. It is still an expression.
it is shorthand of if else